# Is EntityFramework supposed to be that slow?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to create a simple API for my client mobile app. I created new empty `Web API` project and an action but it is extremely slow:

```
[HttpGet, Route("manga")]
public List<MangaDTO> GetList()
{
    using (var mc = new MangaContext()) // Sometimes takes 10s to instantiate the context
    {
        var list = mc.Mangas.ToList(); // Takes ~3.5s to get all
        var mangas = new List<MangaDTO>(); 
        foreach (var o in list) // This loop takes literally forever. ~35s on my server.
            mangas.Add(new MangaDTO(o));
        return mangas;
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to achieve what I want? It takes way too long to get the response, and when I deploy this to my remote server it doesn't even show the result - just the timeout error.

What can I do to make this faster? Also, here is the `MangaContext` class:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class MangaContext : DbContext
{
    private static MangaContext current;

    public static MangaContext Current
    {
        get { if (current == null) current = new MangaContext(); return current; }
    }

    public MangaContext()
    {
        Database.CreateIfNotExists();
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MangaContext>());
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Manga> Mangas { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Alias> Aliases { get; set; }
}
```

Am I missing something here? Because I doubt that instantiating that should take ~10s.

***Edit:***

I removed the `Database.CreateIfNotExists()` call from the Context's constructor. Also, Here is the MangaDTO Class:

```
public class MangaDTO
{
    public MangaDTO(Manga m)
    {
        id = m.Id;
        name = m.Name;
        genres = m.Genres.Select(o => o.Name).ToList();
        author = m.Author;
        artist = m.Artist;
        score = m.Score;
        year = m.Year;
        aliases = m.Aliases.Select(o => o.Name).ToList();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<string> genres { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
    public string artist { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }
    public List<string> aliases { get; set; }
    public int score { get; set; }
}
```

... and the models:

```
public class Manga
{
    public Manga() { }
    public Manga(string name, string desc, string author, string artist, int year, int status, int chapters, string url)
    {
        Name = name;
        Description = desc;
        Author = author;
        Artist = artist;
        Year = year;
        Status = status;
        Url = url;
        Aliases = new List<Alias>();
        Genres = new List<Genre>();
        ChaptersCount = chapters;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }

    public int ChaptersCount { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Alias> Aliases { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Genre> Genres { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

public class Alias
{
    public Alias() { }
    public Alias(string name, Manga manga)
    {
        Name = name;
        Manga = manga;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Manga Manga { get; set; }
}

public class Genre
{
    public Genre() { }
    public Genre(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Mangas = new List<Manga>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Manga> Mangas { get; set; }
}
```

***EDIT 2***

Now it throws an exception on my remote server, but

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.","ExceptionType":"System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException","StackTrace":" at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)\r\n at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)\r\n at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.b__9()\r\n at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)\r\n at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1..GetEnumerator>b__0()\r\n at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()\r\n at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()\r\n at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()\r\n at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n at MangaAPI.Controllers.MangaController.GetList() in C:\\Users\\mrrey\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\XYZ Manga Reader\\MangaAPI\\Controllers\\MangaController.cs:line 39\r\n at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.","ExceptionType":"MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException","StackTrace":" at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ExceptionInterceptor.Throw(Exception exception)\r\n at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.HandleTimeoutOrThreadAbort(Exception ex)\r\n at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n at MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TInterceptionContext,TResult](Func`1 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`1 executing, Action`1 executed)\r\n at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)\r\n at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.","ExceptionType":"System.TimeoutException","StackTrace":" at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)\r\n at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)\r\n at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)\r\n at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)\r\n at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()\r\n at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()\r\n at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)\r\n at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)\r\n at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()\r\n at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.","ExceptionType":"System.IO.IOException","StackTrace":" at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)\r\n at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond","ExceptionType":"System.Net.Sockets.SocketException","StackTrace":" at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)"}}}}}
```

Comment: Are you making changes such that the database is dropped and recreated? At some point you will want to turn that off.

Comment: Is the database located on another server? Hmm but if it is true that the foreach loop takes so much time, then the problem is not your database/EF, because this is all happening in memory. You shouldn't feel anything there..

Comment: @Crowcoder The database is recreated only if the model changes, meaning never, becaue I haven't touched the models in quite a while. This shouldn't be an issue, I think.

Comment: What you can do to avoid the 2nd loop is to use a linq select before retrieving data. So you only pick relevant fields

Comment: @Marc The database is located on my PC (for testing purposes) and on the remote server (but it's still accessed through localhost, because I use it only when I deploy the website to the same server). I know, that'd make the most sense. I do `.ToList()` for a reason here. I do it so that it doesn't take as much time to parse each object into a ViewModel for the API, but it doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Comment: [This is ridiculous](http://imgur.com/a/9fM65).

Comment: (1) Remove `Database.CreateIfNotExists();` from the constructor (2) It's interesting to see your entity model classes and what does `MangaDTO` constructor do - I suspect a lot if lazy loading calls (so called N +1 query issue)

Comment: @IvanStoev I removed the `CreateIfNotExists()` call from the context. I also added the other classes to the original pot. Can you take a lot at them?

Comment: So, as Ivan suspected more or less, there are two separate queries for each `MangaDTO`. You should always monitor SQL statements when performance is slow. That usually gives hints as to where to look further.

Comment: @GertArnold Alright, so how do I go about fixing that? And monitoring the SQL statements as well, for that matter?

Answer (score 2):

I can't say why instantiating a new context takes so long except eventually the code inside the constructor and the db initializer used, so you can try removing them both (replace with `Database.SetInitializer(null);`) and see if that helps.

But the query could definitely be speeded up. Currently you are loading the whole `Manga` table in memory, and then **for each record** there are two more queries executed by

```
genres = m.Genres.Select(o => o.Name).ToList();
```

and

```
aliases = m.Aliases.Select(o => o.Name).ToList();
```

because `m.Genres` and `m.Aliases` are lazy loaded navigation properties. Also note that they first load all the related objects and then `Select(o => o.Name)` is executed in memory by LINQ to Objects.

You can avoid all that by directly projecting to `MangaDTO` like this (single SLQ query, no entity tracking overhead):

```
using (var mc = new MangaContext())
{
    var query = mc.Mangas
        .Select(m => new MangaDTO
        {
            id = m.Id,
            name = m.Name,
            genres = m.Genres.Select(o => o.Name).ToList(),
            author = m.Author,
            artist = m.Artist,
            score = m.Score,
            year = m.Year,
            aliases = m.Aliases.Select(o => o.Name).ToList(),
        });
    var mangas = query.ToList();
    return mangas;
}
```

Make sure to add parameterless constructor to `MangaDTO`. You can now measure the `ToList` call and see how long it takes.

Comment: In fact, there -might- be a Scylla vs. Charybdis, or the current SELECT N+1 problem vs. Monster Join (cartesian product of results): Not sure how EF translates the last code, but if it's with joins, the Manga rows will be multiplied by Genres and Aliases. As long as Manga isn't heavy with large objects, it shouldn't be too bad. Always check your SQL, generated by EF, and, in case of joins, check the size of your result sets.

Comment: @ErikHart You are right for multiplication. What about the fields, luckily here I see 6 Manga fields + 1 Genre field + 1 Alias field.

Comment: As I said, it seems to be not much of a problem for the given schema, as long as Manga doesn't grow heavy and there's not excessive Genres and Aliases. What might be a problem indeed is, if always all Mangas are fetched.

Comment: Thank you @IvanStoev for explaining this. It actually makes sense now. Also, I think you might be right with that multiplication stuff. When I tested your code with VS it worked fine, but when I deployed the API to my remote server it throws an exception on `query.ToList()`.

Comment: It might be only 6 fields + 2, but [the database stores quite a lot of records](http://imgur.com/a/5nHFk),

Comment: @Reynevan Yeah, I understand the overhead of the record multiplication. So you have to find the trade off between single query (with record multiplication) and 2 * N (with big N) small queries. What about the timeout exception, are we sure it's caused by the query? If you  comment out both `genres` and `aliases` assignments inside the `Select`, does it run successfully?

Comment: Hm, it seems it throws the same exception even with the genres& aliases commented out.